# FreeBSD install PECL php7

Tags: php, freebsd, gnupg, pecl

I want to active the gnupg extension for php7. But I can't find a package for pecl for php7.

Does anyone know a way to install pecl for php7 or how to activate gnupg without pecl?

Comment: You could try on of the mailing lists https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/eresources-mail.html or the forum https://forums.freebsd.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can install the pecl-gnupg extension using ports or packages in FreeBSD.

```
pkg install pecl-gnupg
```

or

```
cd /usr/ports/security/pecl-gnupg; make install clean
```

FreeBSD ports has hooks for fetching pecl packages. You can also install pear.